# Global variable is not defined. Success from Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So i´m trying to implement Jquery "Autocomplete" on a input field.
And i like Ajax to fetch "tags" from mysql.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete">
```

I´ve tried several stuff and googled around. I can found larger codes, but this should really be enough!?

**JS**

```
//Get objNr from db
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php',
    success: function(result){
        //Here i make the result global
        objNrs = result;
    }
});
$( "#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: objNrs,
});
```

To se if there was an empty result from php i added `echo 'Hello';`

**PHP**

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    //Here i tried to use `json_encode`
    echo $row['objekt_nr'];
}
echo "Hello";
```

My browser console tell me that `source: objNrs,`
"objNrs is not defined"

So, whats my problem?
Isn´t the variable global at all?

Comment: `var objNrs = result;`

Comment: Where and when do you call that ajax ?

Comment: @aldring27 No, this will make the variable Local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax run asynchronously, so your autocomplete code will execute before the ajax getting success. so you need to write the autocomplete code inside successs event.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php',
    success: function (result) {
        //Here i make the result global
        objNrs = result;
        $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: objNrs,
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: ok. Thats good to know. Ive tried this. And i can see result from php in browser console. But i got a new error `.....-11%22Hello?term=2 403 (Forbidden)` Whats this?

Comment: its forbidden error. checks whether the file needs any authentication for accessing

Comment: @Mjukis: It doesn't matter if you get a new error: The question has been successfully answered, you should accept it as the correct one and, if you want, create a new question to resolve the new error.